# web element not detecting in selenium in a FOR LOOP

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to fetch some information from specific web elements. The problem is that when i try to fetch the information without for loop the program works like a charm. But the same when i put it in a for loop and try it does not detect the web elements in the loop. Here's the code i have been trying:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from lxml import html
import requests
import xlwt



browser = webdriver.Firefox() # Get local session of firefox

# 0 wait until the pages are loaded
browser.implicitly_wait(3) # 3 secs should be enough. if not, increase it

browser.get("http://ae.bizdirlib.com/taxonomy/term/1493") # Load page
links = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2 > a")

def test():#test function
    elems = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content.clearfix > div > fieldset> div > ul > li > span")
    print elems
    for elem in elems:
        print elem.text
    elem1 = browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.content.clearfix>div>fieldset>div>ul>li>a")
    for elems21 in elem1:
        print elems21.text
        return 0


for link in links:
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_UP)
    time.sleep(5)
    test() # Want to call test function    
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
```

The output i get when i print the object is a empty array as the output `[]`. Can somebody help me enhance it. Newbie to selenium.

In the previous question i had asked about printing. But the problem lies is that it self is that the element is not detecting by itself. This way question is totally different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Data not bieng printed in FOR Loop.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32902322/data-not-bieng-printed-in-for-loop)

Comment: No no data was not printing.... here the element is by itself not detecting @MahsumAkbas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldnt open the page but as I understand you want to open links sequencially and do something. With `link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')` you are closing the newly opened tab so your links open in a new tab. In this condition must switch to new window so that you can reach the element in new window. You can query windows by `driver.window_handles` and switch to last window by `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])` and after you closed the window you must switch back to the first window by `driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])`

```
for link in links:
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)

    # switch to new window
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])

    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_UP) # dont know why
    time.sleep(5)
    test() # Want to call test function    
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')

    #switch back to the first window
    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: Thanks a ton... it now calls the function and detects it... but it does not close the current tab. I'm getting this error when i try to close it.

Comment: link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 323, in send_keys
    self._execute(Command.SEND_KEYS_TO_ELEMENT, {'value': typing})
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 404, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 195,

Comment: in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 170, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
StaleElementReferenceException: Message: Element belongs to a different frame than the current one - switch to its containing frame to use it

Comment: `link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w') ` is not correct. link connot be closed :) , window can be closed. correct command is `driver.close()`

Comment: But driver.close() will close the whole browser. I just want to close the current tab after doing some operation.

Comment: No it should just close the assigned driver. May be close didnt switch to new one and closing old one cause this. `driver.quit()` closes all windows.

Comment: This is the code. Tried both driver.close() | driver.quit() .... This closes  the whole browser. Just the tab does not close, can posting the code may be u help me with the code. 

`for link in links:
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.RETURN)
    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.PAGE_UP)
    browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[-1])
    test() # Want to call test function
    browser.quit()
#    link.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'w')
    browser.switch_to_window(browser.window_handles[0])`

Comment: does new windows open a tab on current window or open a seperate window?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91387/discussion-between-mesut-gunes-and-python-learner).